# У нас с коллегой // У меня с коллегой

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число, выбор-варианта

1. У нас с коллегой возник вопрос...
2. У меня с коллегой возник вопрос...

Какой из двух вариантов является правильным?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Думаю, первый вариант более корректный:

*У нас с коллегой возник вопрос...*

По крайней мере, более этичный - автор как бы признаёт равенство коллеги, общность мысли. Второй вариант намекает на собственное главенство - у него возник, а коллега где-то рядом. Это похоже по смыслу на следующую пару предложений:

Мама с дочкой прогуливались по набережной. - Мама с дочкой прогуливалась по набережной. В первом предложении речь о паре "мама + дочка", а во втором мама играет ведущую роль, прогуливалась мама, а дочку или за руку вела, или на руках держала.

Answer (score 1):

*Оба* варианта возможны, но в разных ситуациях: в первом случае вероятнее, что оба хотели (бы) выяснить одно и то же, во втором - скорее всего коллеги поспорили и имеют разные мнения по упомянутому вопросу. Можно усмотреть в одном случае грамматическое "единение" с коллегой, в другом - ненавязчивое размежевание с ним.

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически верны оба варианта.
А вот что касается этикета (насколько понимаю, именно этот момент вы хотите уточнить) или каких-то контекстных особенностей, то тут сложнее.

Людмила в общем-то права, когда говорила, что "у меня с коллегой" предполагаяет более активную роль первого лица ("меня"), а "у нас" - коллективную.

Но во втором случае возникает сомнение в универсальности формулы.

Во-первых, зачем упоминание о коллеге, если и так ясно, что "нас" - это я и он?
Может, говорящий пальцем показал на "коллегу"? Но тогда это явно не образец для подражания (особенно, если придерживаться европейского или ближневосточного этикета, а азиатов и американцев понятия несколько другие). Вот если бы "у меня с коллегой Имярековым", то понятно.

Есть и во-вторых. Коли вообще речь действительно зашла о этикете, то есть универсальная английская формула. *Джентльмен скажет: "Мой пес и я вчера были на охоте". И никогда не ошибется.* Думаю, коллегу, если ситуация позволяет, стоит упомянуть первым.

***У моего коллеги и меня возник вопрос.*** 
Это предельно чопорно, но беспроигрышно. Впрочем, вопросы этикета несколько выходят за рамки формата ресурса, так что не смею навязывать.